# 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.' when encrypted bytes is saved as string and then decrypted

Tags: c#, encryption

I am trying to save encrypted bytes to a file and then decrypt them later.

I have and Ecrypt Method that looks like:

```
      public static byte[] EncryptString(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
      {
           // Check arguments
           if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
           {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
           }
           if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
           {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
           }
           if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
           {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");
           }

           byte[] encrypted;

           // Create an AES object with the specified key and IV
           using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
           {
                aes.Key = key;
                aes.IV = iv;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                     using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                     {
                          using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                          {

                               //Write all data to the stream
                               swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                          }
                          encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                     }
                }
           }

           // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream
           return encrypted;
      }
```

and a Decrypt Method that looks like:

```
      public static string DecryptString(byte[] encryptedText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
      {
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
           {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, new AesCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(key,iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                     cs.Write(encryptedText,0, encryptedText.Length);
                     cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                     return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
           }
      }
```

Then I have written several unit tests that look like this:

```
      //This unit test Passes.
      [TestMethod()]
      public void Decrypt_bytes_ShouldDecryptTheString()
      {
           //Arrange
           var password = "test";
           var b = AESEncryption.EncryptString(password, Key, Iv);

           //Act
           var decryptedValue = AESEncryption.DecryptString(b, Key, Iv);

           //Assert
           Assert.AreEqual(password, decryptedValue);
      }


      //this one gives the error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"
      [TestMethod()]
      public void EncriptToString_ConvertBack_ShouldDecript()
      {
           //Arrange
           var password = "test";

           //Act
           var b = AESEncryption.EncryptString(password, Key, Iv);
           var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);

           var nb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);

           var result = AESEncryption.DecryptString(nb, Key, Iv);

           //Assert
           Assert.AreEqual(password, result);
      }
```

Can someone please explain why I'm getting an error when I convert a string to bytes and change it but not when I just use the bytes?

Comment: where would I add that?

Comment: I was able to successfully encrypt and decrypt a string with no exceptions. Can you post a simple example of how you call it from start to finish?

Comment: Note that you shuld not arbitrarily convert a byte array to a string, as this will almost suredly be a lossy process.

Comment: If you want to convert an arbitrary byte array to a string, you should use `Convert.ToBase64String(b)` instead, and the corresponding to convert back, as this will not be lossy.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sure, one moment. I will do this.

Comment: @3xGuy `aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;`

Comment: The problem are these two: `var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
var nb = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);` you have lost data in this conversion. There is no guarantee that an arbitrary sequence of bytes can be converted to a string that will then convert back to the same bytes. Don't use this way of converting to a string and back, use Base64 or Base85 or something similar that is not a lossy process.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How should I convert this to a string?

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String(b)` will give you a string from the byte array, then use the corresponding FromBase64String to get the byte array back.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! That was the issue!